# How can I summarize many different lists and sort them in Python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

Let's say I have a data set like the following.

```
Group A
i.   [4, 7, 3, 5, 8]
ii.  [2, 6, 0, 5, 7]
iii. [9, 0, 1 ,8, 9]

Group B
i.   [6, 6, 2, 7, 3]

Group C
i.   [5, 9, 2, 1, 1]
ii.  [1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
iii. [8, 3, 3, 3, 0]
iv.  [4, 1, 8, 0, 3]

Group D
i.   [0, 3, 5, 0, 7]
ii.  [8, 4, 2, 8, 3]
```

etc. My actual data set has a lot more than just four groups of numbers.

What I'm trying to do is find out what the data set of five numbers adds up to for every combination of one data set per group. So, for example, *`Group A-i`*`+`*`Group B-i`*`+`*`Group C-i`*`+`*`Group D-i`*`= [(4+6+5+0), (7+6+9+3), (3+2+2+5), (5+7+1+0), (8+3+1+7)] = [15, 25, 12, 13, 19]. Do that for`*`A-ii`*`+`*`B-i`*`+`*`C-iii`*`+`*`D-ii`*, etc., every possible combo. Then, have all those added up groups in a list so I can further sort and use them.

I tried to enter the data as a bunch of lists but I have no idea how to even add the many lists together. I think adding each list to a list of lists might work but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to the one from Daralet but using numpy.sum to get the total. In addition, not flattening the list.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

list_a = [[4, 7, 3, 5, 8], [2, 6, 0, 5, 7], [9, 0, 1 ,8, 9]]
list_b = [[6, 6, 2, 7, 3]]
list_c = [[5, 9, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 5, 7, 8], [8, 3, 3, 3, 0], [4, 1, 8, 0, 3]]
list_d = [[0, 3, 5, 0, 7], [8, 4, 2, 8, 3]]

all_groups = [list_a, list_b, list_c, list_d]

combinations = list(itertools.product(*all_groups))

np_sums =  [np.sum(combination, axis=0) for combination in combinations]
print(np_sums)
```

Results

```
[array([15, 25, 12, 13, 19]),
 array([23, 26,  9, 21, 15]),
 array([11, 18, 15, 19, 26]),
 array([19, 19, 12, 27, 22]),
 array([18, 19, 13, 15, 18]),
 array([26, 20, 10, 23, 14]),
 array([14, 17, 18, 12, 21]),
 array([22, 18, 15, 20, 17]),
 array([13, 24,  9, 13, 18]),
 array([21, 25,  6, 21, 14]),
 array([ 9, 17, 12, 19, 25]),
 array([17, 18,  9, 27, 21]),
 array([16, 18, 10, 15, 17]),
 array([24, 19,  7, 23, 13]),
 array([12, 16, 15, 12, 20]),
 array([20, 17, 12, 20, 16]),
 array([20, 18, 10, 16, 20]),
 array([28, 19,  7, 24, 16]),
 array([16, 11, 13, 22, 27]),
 array([24, 12, 10, 30, 23]),
 array([23, 12, 11, 18, 19]),
 array([31, 13,  8, 26, 15]),
 array([19, 10, 16, 15, 22]),
 array([27, 11, 13, 23, 18])]
```